# Boot Camp Windows 7 shows Vista boot screen after setting up with Parallels 5

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, parallels, multi-boot

I have a Windows 7 Professional installation set up using Boot Camp, alongside Mac OS X Snow Leopard on my MacBook. My MacBook boots Mac OS X by default. The other day I decided to take Parallels Desktop 5 for a ride, but being lazy to set up a Windows 7 VM, I chose to use my Boot Camp installation instead.

Everything worked while Parallels was still installed, *except* when I boot into Windows through Boot Camp as opposed to using Parallels, I see Windows Vista's boot screen instead of Windows 7's. Vista's boot screen is the one with the green progress bar and a copyright notice.

I know Windows 7 actually uses that boot screen in machines with low screen resolutions, but it's still on my MacBook's native 1280x800 resolution when I boot back. Therefore I suspect this is a Parallels issue since I'm aware that Windows overreacts to being virtualized by it. (Or, I suspect, the resolution is low when booting but OK after reaching the welcome screen.)

I've cleanly uninstalled Parallels from my MacBook since I've decided I'm happy with using Boot Camp by itself, but the Vista boot screen still shows. After some searching I could only find [this article](http://windows7center.com/images/fix-windows-7-boot-screen-shows-a-vista-boot-screen-instead). It says I can run the following command with elevated privileges to restore the boot screen:

```
bcdedit /set {current} locale en-US
```

But it has no effect; the Vista boot screen is still there. Here's the output of `bcdedit` (without any parameters):

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {ae8252c0-a80a-11df-bce1-d21bf61174b0}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {ae8252c2-a80a-11df-bce1-d21bf61174b0}
recoveryenabled         Yes
graphicsmodedisabled    Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {ae8252c0-a80a-11df-bce1-d21bf61174b0}
nx                      OptIn
```

So it's pretty obvious that was a solution to the wrong problem. The system/boot locale seems irrelevant to this situation.

Is there anything else I can try (besides reinstalling Windows, that is)?

Comment: Is it really that much of a bother to you? If Windows 7 is launching correctly, despite the boot screen, how much of a problem is it really, apart from being cosmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run an elevated prompt with:

```
 bcdboot %WinDir% /l en-US
```

Comment: Well, this did the trick after all. Could've sworn I saw it elsewhere but didn't figure to try it. Thanks!